# create https binding on IIS10

Tags: https

We have a website that is hosted on IIS 7.5. it is accessible only via https binding. the application has svc services that are called from javascript.
recently we moved to IIS 10 and access to svc got broken.

I tried to modify web.config, but not sure what I have to change.
here is web.config sections for services:

```
`<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="AuthorizationModule" type="AuthorizationModule" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add path="APPortal.axd" verb="GET,POST" name="PdfHttpHandler" type="APPortalUI.Web.HttpHandler.PdfHttpHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
      <!--<add name=".svc" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        -->
       <add name="svc-integrated" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
...
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400" />
        <verbs>
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svc" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GRADS.MenuItemServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
...
<serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataAndDebug">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
          <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" 
    />
    <services>
      <service name="GRADS.MenuItemService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="GRADS.MenuItemServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpDefaultBinding" contract="GRADS.MenuItemService" />
      </service>
...
</services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpDefaultBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="8388608" maxBufferSize="8388608" maxBufferPoolSize="8388608">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="8388608" maxBytesPerRead="8388608" maxNameTableCharCount="8388608" maxStringContentLength="8388608" />
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
...
`
```

this configuration worked perfectly in IIS 7.5, but when I try access services in IIS 10, the following error is thrown:

Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

and also:
The service '/services/xxxxService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +607194
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +231
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +33
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +798
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +91

the services are created as svc files in vb.net:
for example:

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")> _
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode:=InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode:=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)> _
Public Class xxxxService

    <OperationContract()> _
    <Web.WebGet()> _
    Public Function Foo() As String

    end function

end class
```

Can someone point out how or where to fix it?
I'd assume that moving from IIS7 to IIS10 shouldn't be that painful.

thanks